# How do I get lots of players to join my clan in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

I don't have many members in my clan, and would like to recruit more, but almost everyone is already in a clan (yes I looked in recruiting). When I do get a new player in my clan, they are inactive for 5 days so I kick them.

How can I effectively recruit people for my clan?

Comment: FYI: The higher your clan tier, the higher your clan research multiplier is.

Answer (score 8):

### Advertise, research, network and invest

Make sure you're recruiting on several regions if you want a diverse, larger clan. Focus on newer players, as they're less likely to already be affiliated.

Asking during missions or in relays is a valid strategy too. Joining early missions and helping newbies might get you some new players who could use the help.

Start and, if possible, finish as many research projects as you can by yourself so people are more tempted to join for blueprints and Empyrean rooms.

Join an Alliance to increase your reach and meet new people.

Make a good looking Dojo and Icon to get the attention of more aesthetically-inclined players.